# why recursion not breaking at end in java

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I just started learning recursion in Java but I can't understand how recursion is working. But it looks like three line code. Is there any easy way to learn recursion, nested recursion, deep learning about recursion?

```java
package roughworkp;

public class r_class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(check(5));
    }

    public static int check(int root) {
        int c = 0;
        if (root == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.print("first");
        int l = check(root - 1);
        System.out.print("in l" + l + " ");

        int r = check(root - 1);
        System.out.println("in r" + r + " ");
//      System.out.print("i am in here"+" "+(++c)+" ");
//      ++c;
//      System.out.println();
        return Math.max(l, r)+1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
firstfirstfirstfirstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in l2 firstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in r2
in l3 firstfirstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in l2 firstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in r2
in r3
in l4 firstfirstfirstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in l2 firstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in r2
in l3 firstfirstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in l2 firstfirstin l0 in r0
in l1 firstin l0 in r0
in r1
in r2
in r3
in r4
5
```

I also commented some line why `c` is not increasing and `return` statement don't break the recursion at the end and find the max value every time.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: all your variables are local variables. each time you enter the recursion, they are initialized again in a new memory address. that is why, for instance, c is not increasing.

Comment: My question is how the last line 5 is the output because I am finding the max value +1 and sending 5 as the parameter then the output is should be 6? @tgdavies

Comment: Thanks @TomElias for your explain but how I can understand recursion without using paper and pen. **Not only these problems**